# Circular Dependency in Parser Grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, yacc

I am trying to build my first parser. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the theory of grammars and now I wonder whether it is

- plainly forbidden
- just a bad idea or
- kind of OK

to have circular dependencies in my grammar. My intuition raises a yellow flag, but since I am not familiar with the theory of parsers, I am not sure.

Be my lexer well-defined and be its tokens the ones one would expect from their names, then I have the following grammar:

```
list_content    : value
                | list_content COMMA list_content

list            : LBRACE list_content RBRACE

value           : INT
                | list
```

In there, `value` depends on `list`, `list` depends on `list_content` and `list_content` depends on `value`.

I have seen recursive definitions in grammars before, such as:

```
sum             | NUMBER + NUMBER
                | NUMBER + sum
                | LBRACE sum RBRACE
```

However, I think, my circular definition is different (in terms of: dirtier), because it is harder to overview and the definitory circle spans multiple grammar rules. I am not sure, whether my circular definition creates an ambiguity in my grammar. I also fear it might make my code hard to debug.

So, I have two questions:

A) **Should I restructure** my grammar (and my lexer) or is it OK to live with this circular definition?

B) **If I should restructure, how would I best do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A circular dependence like this is fine -- it's a recursive definition and is analogous to using recursion in a program.  As such, the important thing to look at is how the base case is realized, since that is how the recusion terminates.  If you don't have a base case (or it can't be reached without also triggering additional recursion), you have a problem -- an infinite loop that can never match any finite input.

In your case, the base case is the `primitive` rule -- since `value` can reduce to a single `primitive` and `list_content` to a single `value`, everything is fine.

You do have one issue in your grammar in that the rule

```
list_content: list_content COMMA list_content
```

is ambiguous.  What this means is that for any list with three or more elements (two or more COMMAs), there are multiple way to parse it -- either matching the left comma (left recursive) or the right comma (right recursive) first.  This will cause problems with most parser tools that cannot deal with ambiguity, and in you case is probably irrelevant (you don't really care which way it is parsed, since you'll likely just concatenate the lists).

The fix for this is to rewrite the rule as a simple left- or right- recusive rule (but not both).  Which you want to use depends on the parser style you are using -- for an LL (top down or recursive descent) parser, you want a right recursive rule.  For an LR (bottom up or shift/reduce) parser, you (generally) want a left recursive rule.

- left recursive: `list_content : value | list_content COMMA value ;`
- right recursive: `list_content : value | value COMMA list_content ;`

Comment: I edited my post after I realized that the grammar I initially posted was not a minimal example of my problem. I removed the `primitive` rule and just put the terminating token `INT` instead. The core problem has basically not changed, and your answer is still a valid and very good answer to the problem. However, if you want later readers of the thread to understand your answer more easily, you might want to apply the minor update to your answer necessary to keep it in accordance with the updated version of the question. Sorry for the confusion and the resulting extra work!